# Как использовать SharedPreferences в классе?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences

Мне нужно сохранить или получить данные из файла, используя SharedPreferences в стороннем классе вне активности.

Как это сделать?

"This" я передать смог, а как создать SharedPreferences в классе, не знаю. Приложение падает.
Вот код:

```
private Context temp;

private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public Dialog_sil(Context temps){
    temp=temps;


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(temps);

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}
```

Comment: как только заикнулся про падение, сразу стактрейс прикрепляй. Без стактрейса жаловаться на падения запрещено.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое стактрейс.

Comment: Не на одном языке не встречал такого понятия как стактрейс

Comment: И сказать почему не шлю лог? Потамучто он пишет что ошибка в android api

Comment: А, тогда обычное дело. Нужно подождать, пока Гугл исправит. В Андроид 6, возможно, заработает. P.S. Как вам сказали, выкладывайте лог или полностью проект

Comment: Думаю не в андроиде дело!

Comment: ОО нашел пример, который мне нужен, не пойму как но ему понадобились другие void init и еще что-то, вот пример http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/01/25/android-sohranenie-dannyh-v-postoyannoe-hranilische.html

Comment: Особенность такая проверять не пуст ли классик if( settings == null ){
            InitSharedPreferences();
        }

Answer (score 2):

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()
```

Или можно просто передать в класс экземпляр `Context` или самого `SharedPreferences`

Исходник класса:

```
 class Example
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        public Example(Context context)
        {
            sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("Example",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("test","test");
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```

Инициализация в onCreate:

```
Example example=new Example(this);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Example",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s=sharedPreferences.getString("test","--");
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Попробуйте подобным образом реализовать, у меня все заработало.

Comment: Context я передаю, но падения получаю.

Comment: Попробуй в Activity получить SharedPrferences и передать его в класс.

Comment: А какой Exception получаешь?

Comment: private Context temp;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    private Toast toast;

    public Dialog_sil(Context temps){
        temp=temps;
        //editor=etemp;


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(temps);

        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

Comment: Падение на строчке         editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

Comment: Он не знает что такое MODE_PRIVATE, красным мигает студия.

Comment: Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: Падает всеравно, at ux.project.chat.uchat.Dialog_sil.<init>(Dialog_sil.java:28)
            at ux.project.chat.uchat.Autorizes.<init>(Autorizes.java:44)

Comment: sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("Example", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: не `context.MODE_PRIVATE`, а `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`. А вообще, загляните, например, сюда http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Comment: Да знаю что это за сайт, хороший сайт, но там обычный sharedPreferences который у меня работал, но сейчас используется класс который используется во всех активностях и вот такие падения.

Comment: "не context.MODE_PRIVATE, а Context.MODE_PRIVATE": приложение всеравно падает!